# ML: How to create a simple machine learning model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to machine learning. I try to make the simplest model but different from all "hello world" tutorials.

I don't have a very big data sets so I decided to train the model that will determine if the input number is odd or even.

```py
# create a model that defines if number is odd or even
def generate_data(length, is_random=False):
    res = []
    for i in range(0, length):
        number = i if not is_random else random.randrange(0, 99999)

        if number % 2 != 0:
            res.append([number, 1])
        else:
            res.append([number, 0])
    return res


train_data = generate_data(5000, is_random=True)

data_set = np.array(train_data)
random_number = data_set[:, 0:1]
is_random_number_even = data_set[:, 1]

print('X: {}'.format(random_number))
print('Y: {}'.format(is_random_number_even))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(random_number, is_random_number_even, epochs=100, batch_size=30)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(random_number, is_random_number_even)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

In this code I generate an input data to train model, create a model with 2 internal layers and with different number of nodes (it's written in tutorial that there is no rules for number of layers and notes in every layer) and try to train it.

The problem is that the accuracy is always about 50%, sometimes I had 52% when I change the number of layers and nodes in every layer but never more. It seems that despite of a lot of reading about this topic I'm still missing something.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong here and what is a correct direction to proceed?

Comment: Nowadays, we never use `sigmoid` activation except for output layers; change all other activations to `relu`

Comment: I don't think this is a good sample task. I might be missing something but I do believe odd-even is a rather difficult function to learn for a simple NN. You might want to look at something more easily separable, e.g. "is the number bigger or smaller than 10".